# Node JS - wait for full response

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

So I have an API (written in PHP over Nginx).
I use Node JS in order to send requests to that API.
Sometimes it takes 5-7 seconds until the API finishes what it needs to do.

The problem is that Node JS doesn't wait for the full response to arrive.

```
http.get(url, function(response){
    // called right away instead of waiting until it finishes
});
```

I already tried using the .end() & .close() events - no luck.
How can I make NodeJS to wait? or...how do I make PHP to notify node "hey, now I've finished".
Thanks.

One important thing: when I try to CURL to the API, it does wait for the full response.

Comment: And, what is in the `response` object that is returned?  Did you look?  Did you read how `http.get()` works in the node.js documentation?

Answer (score 1):

When using the native http client you will have to manually append the chunks before parsing the data. For this reason, most people do not use the native http client. You want to use something like the `request` module.

```
npm install request
```

Followed by

```
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I tried using request module but there's no change. the callback function fires immediately, even that the API is still working. any clues?

Comment: If your php application ends the http connection and THEN continues on doing more work, then there's nothing you can do in this case. The php app either has to 1) wait to close the connection until it finishes doing all the work OR 2) expose a "status" API, which would somehow respond with the status of the task, so that the node app can poll it, and then fire the callback once it is confirmed that the task is complete.

Comment: Yuri, that is my question. how do I do what you suggested? how do I make PHP to close the connection only AFTER everything is done?

Comment: I've never programmed in php, but looking at this document http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php it appears that `flush();` `ob_flush();` `session_write_close();` deal with closing the connection. So I suppose don't call those until everything is finished?

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS works in a fully asynchronous manner. This means that all code is executed, top-to-bottom, without waiting for any functions with callbacks.

Coming from PHP, you're expecting it to do:

```
ExecuteThis();
ThenThis();
AndFinallyThis();
```

But NodeJS doesn't do that. It'll just start executing everything at once and then return the result. Which is like running this command:

```
php ExecuteThis.php && php ThenThis.php && php AndFinallyThis.php
```

What you want is an [asynchronous waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async), a [callback](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks), a [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/), or a structure of that sort, coupled with a [HTTP request](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request).

Comment: Thanks Adam but I'm not new to JS. It's not what the question is about.

Comment: Ah, no worries. Saw that you were having issues w/ it not waiting for "the full response" - that's usually because of the async issue w/ JS. I'll leave this answer here in case anyone else has the issue but is new to the Node side of the world.